# How to properly implement strict comparison and modulo operator

Tags: javascript

I have written this code for the udacity course I am taking and am unsure what I need to change in order to receive the correct answer

I'm being asked to write a code that prints "even" if it is an even number and "odd" if it is an odd number

When I run the code it gives me the desired response so I'm unsure why I am receiving the feedback that I "need to use strict comparison in my conditional statement" and that I need to use the modulo operator to determine whether the number is even or odd

I need someone to point out how to write a more "strict" comparison and to use (or properly use because I thought I was using it) the modulo operator.

```
var number = 19;

if (number % 2) {console.log ("odd");

} else { console.log ("even"); 

}
```

Comment: Have a look here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity

Comment: `number % 2 === …` …?

Comment: You're not doing a comparison to anything, you're just creating the value of `number%2` and testing how [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) it is.

Answer (score 4):

Your code works because `number % 2` will always be `0` or `1` if number is an integer.Now `1` is truthy value and `0` is flasy.For all odd numbers `number % 2` will return `1` and `1` is truthy value so considering `number` is `19`.

```
if(number % 2)
if(1)
if(true) //block will executed.
```

But if number is ever it would return `0` and `if(0)` is same as `if(false)` and code will jump to `else` block.

Compare the result with `0` using `===`.

```js
var number = 19;

if (number % 2 === 0) {
  console.log("even");

} else {
  console.log("odd");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a `===` comparison operator alongside the modulo operator `%`.
Although what you're doing is not wrong, I believe the statement Udacity is expecting is something like this:

```js
var number = 19;

if (number % 2 === 0) {
  console.log ("even");
} else { 
  console.log ("odd"); 
}
```

**Strict vs normal comparison**

Now when you use the double equal to sign `==`, JS engine will try to cast the operands and see if they match. In other words, its type will not be compared.

If you however use triple equal to `===`, then JS engine will not cast the operands and along with the value its type will also be compared.

In normal comparison: `"10" == 10` will return `true`
In strict, the above expression will return `false`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var number = 19;

if (number % 2 === 0) {console.log ("even");

} else { console.log ("odd"); 

}
```

Comment: @NoChance Maybe because of no explanation.

Comment: no idea why it was downvoted. Thanks anyway for the upvote and neutralizing the negative :)

Comment: @MaheerAli hmmm that may be it.